# perror() give seg. fault

Tags: c, linux, gcc, posix, errno

After an error occurs, I call `perror()`, naturally. But I'm getting a segmentation fault when I do this or   `printf("error: %s\n", strerror(errno));` I have no idea what is happing.

```
  int fd;
  if((fd = open(FILENAME, O_RDONLY)) == -1) {
    perror("fbi");
    exit(1);
  }

  for(;;) {

    readed = read(fd, buffer, BUFSIZE);

    if(readed == 0)
      break;

    if(readed == -1) {
      perror("fbi"); // <- here's the error
      exit(1);
    }
```

How to fix this?

**Update:**

```
printf("%d\n", errno); // given 9
```

**UPDATE2:**

Looks like there is a relation with the buffer size passed in the `recv()` function. if `BUFSIZE` is `1`, give the above error. But if `BUFSIZE` is e.g, `128` **no error**. Can someone explain this behavior?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger such as gdb?  What's the call stack?

Comment: sounds possible that (1) you're out of stack space or (2) you overran a buffer on the stack and wrote over the return address (though this 2nd one would probably have to require some funky stuff like other threads)

Comment: @AdamRosenfield: by using gdb I found that the error is from `getenv()` function: `0xb7e84011 in getenv () from /lib/libc.so.6`

Comment: Make sure you are passing a valid C-string to getenv().

Comment: I'm not calling getenv(). perror() calls it

Comment: can you show the essence of "thread apply all bt full" (while looking at coredump with gdb) output here and try running the app under valgrind?

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to know exactly what is wrong from this snippet. But in general, the answer to the question "why do I segfault when calling [rock solid c library func here]?" is usually: your stack is fried. The read, is of course a prime suspect.

Answer (score 1):

Be certain to `#include <string.h>`, etc. .

---

I was using `#include <errno.h>[...]printf("%s\n",strerror(errno));[...]` without problems for days inside a macro.  Then one day I add another call to `strerror(errno)`, the results included bizarre behavior, segmentation faults, incorrect return types, unexpected program termination (with exit status 0), all depending on how I called this second `strerror` call.

Something as simple as `strerror(errno)==NULL` would result in `warning: comparison between pointer and integer`.

Turns out it was because I used `strerror` without `#include <string.h>`.  Since the function *is* being correctly linked as part of the standard c library, the compiler creates a (standards mandated) "implicit declaration" of the function which assumes a definition of `int strerror(int)`.  The incompatible return types cause the issues, since on my system `char*` is 64 bits but `int` is 32 bits.  So depending on how the compiler arranges the memory space sometimes pointers will fit in 32 bits, sometimes they won't, sometimes the incorrect addresses happen to match other allocated pages of memory(undefined/blank output), sometimes they don't(segmentation fault).  I happened to get in a situation where it didn't fit in 32 bits and the compiler "cast" the return value to a 32 bit `int` and then cast it back (for `printf`) to a 64 bit `char*` (without the missing upper half of the 64 bits which are now zero), and undefined behavior ensues as the processor attempts to read from unallocated memory pages.

Diagnosing your particular case will require a [short, self contained, compilable, example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/), for example you make reference to a `recv` function call (I assume you meant read?).

You will need to also include the command you used to compile your code, as the order of linking commands, for example, can, potentially, significatly change the behavior of the resulting code.